# Make LibreOffice presentation open website (hyperlink) when clicking on image?

Tags: libreoffice, hyperlink, presentations, mouse-click

I know I can use Insert > Hyperlink to create a *text* that, when clicked on, opens a website.

Can also do something similar with an image? Or just any object in general?

I know I can right click on objects and choose Interaction, which can open documents or play videos etc, but unfortunately there is no "Open URL" or "Visit Website" action in there. Is there another way to pull this off?

Note that working around it by using the 'Run program' action isn't really what I need, because I need this presentation to work on different machines (with different OSes even). So running a particular browser program on my PC may not work on someone else's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following works (at least, it does in Ubuntu):-

- Insert your image: the corners and mid-side markers will be in green to show that it is selected.
- Click within the image, causing the markers to turn red and a sight symbol to appear, as here:

[image: Impress Slide]

- You can now click `Insert` -> `Hyperlink...` (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>) and insert your link.
- If you now click outside the image the markers will disappear, and clicking within the image will trigger the link, whether in edit or slide-show mode.

The only slight aesthetic problem is that hovering within the image causes the pop-up text `Go to document: http://LinkAddress`. I have not investigated if this can be customised.

Comment: Works here on OS X as well!